# "Google Cloud" connection not listed when adding new connection on Airflow Webserver

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, airflow-webserver

I installed the google provider with

```
pip install 'apache-airflow[google]'
```

and also tried

```
pip install apache-airflow-providers-google
```

But  I can not find `Google Cloud` option when adding a new connection via `airflow webserver`, as shown below:
[image]

All I found is `Google Dataprep`.

I have tried to restart the webserver multiple times but the `Google Cloud` option is still not listed. It returns this info when I'm starting the webserver:

```
{providers_manager.py:215} INFO - Optional provider feature disabled when importing 'airflow.providers.google.leveldb.hooks.leveldb.LevelDBHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package
```

Also tried to set `lazy_discover_providers = False` on the `airflow.cfg` with no luck.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem with MWAA. I had two option to create the connection:

1. using [Airflow CLI](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.4/howto/connection.html#creating-a-connection-from-the-cli). To simplify creating it with CLI, I suggest to generate it with python, then run the script in your CLI:

```py
import json
from airflow.models.connection import Connection

connection_extra = {
    "extra__google_cloud_platform__key_path":"path/to/key",
    "extra__google_cloud_platform__key_secret_name": "key_file_name_if_it_is_stored_in_secret_manager",
    "extra__google_cloud_platform__keyfile_dict":"{"
        "\"type\": \"service_account\","
        " \"project_id\": \"<PROJECT_ID>\","
        " \"private_key_id\": \"<PRIVATE_KEY_ID>\","
        " \"private_key\": \"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\\n<PRIVATE_KEY>\\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\\n\","
        " \"client_email\": \"<CLIENT_EMAIL>\","
        " \"client_id\": \"<CLIENT_ID>\","
        " \"auth_uri\": \"https://<AUTH_URI>\","
        " \"token_uri\": \"https://<TOKEN_URI>\","
        " \"auth_provider_x509_cert_url\": \"https://<AUTH_CERT_URI>\","
        " \"client_x509_cert_url\": \"https://<CLIENT_CERT_URI>\""
    "}",
    "extra__google_cloud_platform__num_retries":"5",
    "extra__google_cloud_platform__project":"PROJECR_NAME",
    "extra__google_cloud_platform__scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
}

c = Connection(
    conn_id="gcp_conn",
    conn_type="google-cloud-platform",
    description="A connection to access GCP resources",
    extra=connection_extra
)

my_connection_json = {
    "conn_type": c.conn_type,
    "login": c.login,
    "password": c.password,
    "host":c.host,
    "port": c.port,
    "schema": c.schema,
    "extra": c.extra
}

print(f"airflow connections add '{c.conn_id}' --conn-json '{json.dumps(my_connection_json)}'")
```

You can run this script on your scheduler host, it will be print an Airlfow CLI command, copy, paste and run it in a terminal to create the connection.

2. from the UI with type `http` (you are not supposed to set all the variables), you can check this [doc](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/connections/gcp.html#configuring-the-connection):

```json
{
   "extra__google_cloud_platform__project":"<POJECT NAME>",
   "extra__google_cloud_platform__key_path":"",
   "extra__google_cloud_platform__keyfile_dict":{
      "type":"service_account",
      "project_id":"<PROJECT ID>",
      "private_key_id":"<PRIVATE KEY ID>",
      "private_key":"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n<PRIVATE KEY>\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
      "client_email":"<CLIENT EMAIL>",
      "client_id":"<CLIENT ID>",
      "auth_uri":"https://<AUTH URI>",
      "token_uri":"https://<TOKEN URI>",
      "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://<AUTH CERT URI>",
      "client_x509_cert_url":"https://<CLIENT CERT URI>"
   },
   "extra__google_cloud_platform__scope":"",
   "extra__google_cloud_platform__num_retries":"10"
}
```

You can also create it using an environment variable, but it's not secure:

```bash
export AIRFLOW_CONN_GOOGLE_CLOUD_DEFAULT='google-cloud-platform://?extra__google_cloud_platform__project=<PROJECT_NAMR>&extra__google_cloud_platform__scope=<SCOPE>&extra__google_cloud_platform__key_path=<KEY_PATH>&extra__google_cloud_platform__num_retries=10'
```

Comment: Hi Hussein, thanks so much for helping!

I'm also exploring the CLI but it doesn't work so far. Do you have a step-by-step example of how to do this? (what should I input into the CLI)

`from the UI with type http (you are not supposed to set all the variables), you can check this doc`

On which file should I put the JSON you attached? and what do you mean by "UI with type http"?

Thanks!

Comment: By `HTTP` type, I mean you can create a connection via the UI, and instead of selecting `Google Cloud` which is not in your connection types list, you can choose `HTTP` and add the extra dict. For the CLI, I will add an example to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

please try to upgrade your db using 'airflow db upgrade'. Once it did, then you can restart the server. I faced a table creation error while upgrading, then I had to remove the db and initialize it again. Obviously it's not advisable since it removes history. If you don't have anything to preserve, you can check that as well.